# A simple question: Material-UI TextField, how to set different font size in different breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I think it's just a simple task in HTML/CSS but in Material-UI, how to set different font size for TextField in Material-UI?

The following code does not work:

```
<TextField
    name="keyword"
    InputProps={{
        style: styles.textField
    }}
    placeholder="Type here"
/>
const styles = {
    textField: {
        fontSize: 16,
        '@media (min-width: 576px)': {
            fontSize: 20
        },
        '@media (min-width: 768px)': {
            fontSize: 22
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

to change the font size of `TextField` with `media-query`, target the root input class by using the `InputProps` prop, and select the `input` class. classes provided in `InputProps` is applied to the `input` element.

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.textFieldStyle} }}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

Now style the `textFeildStyle` class inside the `makeStyles` and for adding `@media-queries` use the `theme.breakpoints` method. It is explained [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#breakpoints).

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    [theme.breakpoints.down("lg")]: {
        textFieldStyle: {
            color: "yellow",
            fontSize: 19
        }
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
        textFieldStyle: {
            color: "green",
            fontSize: 17
        }
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
        textFieldStyle: {
            color: "blue",
            fontSize: 15
        }
    }
}));
```

Working sandbox demo:
[image: Edit textField with media-query]

Comment: Working with mui for the first time and this was very helpful. If only this could be edited using the xs, md and lg props directly on the components. To anyone reading this and there is another way out, please provide links.